# SQL query not getting it right

Tags: sql, join

I have a table (BUDDY) with these attributes

- id
- requestor
- requested
- status

if the status='a' means that requestor and requested are buddies
 however how can i know the buddies of a certain user if the user can either be a requestor and a requested?

```
SELECT requestor, requested
FROM buddy,user 
WHERE user_id = requestor or user_id = requested
```

this is giving me multiple values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get some fields from the user, you need to join `buddy` to the `user` table. Otherwise, you are going to get an uncorrelated cross-join.

However, it does not look like you need any of the user's columns, so a simple change below should do the trick:

```
SELECT requestor, requested
FROM buddy
WHERE user_id = requestor or user_id = requested
```

If you want to add fields from the user, add a join:

```
SELECT b.requestor, b.requested, u.first_name, u.last_name
FROM buddy b
JOIN user u ON b.requestor=u.id OR b.requested=u.id
WHERE user_id = b.requestor or user_id = b.requested
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a user U

```
SELECT requestor
FROM buddy
WHERE requested = U AND status='a'
UNION
SELECT requested
FROM buddy
WHERE requestor = U AND status='a'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```
SELECT b.requested  AS MyBuddy
FROM buddy AS b
INNER JOIN user AS u1 u1.user_id = b.requestor
WHERE  buddy.status = 'a'
AND u1.user_id = 101

UNION

SELECT b.requestor AS MyBuddy
FROM buddy AS b
INNER JOIN user AS u2 u2.user_id = b.requested
WHERE  buddy.status = 'a'
AND u2.user_id = 101
```

The first query searches the `requestor` for the user in question and if the status is `a` then it pulls the `requested` as the `MyBuddy`.  The second query searches the `requested` for the user in question and if the status is `a` then it pulls the `requested` as the `MyBuddy`.  Then you UNION the two queries together to get the complete list.

I joined to the `user` table because likely you will want to use something like `u1.name` instead of `b.requested` and `b.requestor` in the SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

Just join to `user` for both conditions:

```
SELECT requestor, requested, u.user_name AS Buddy
FROM buddy b
INNER JOIN user u 
  ON (@userID = requestor AND b.requested = u.user_id)
  OR (@userID = requested AND b.requestor = u.user_id)
WHERE status = 'a'
```